# How can I find out the developer of an app from its APK file?

Tags: applications, apk

Given only an APK file, how can I find out the developer of a non-market Android application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "non-techy way" would be, given the `package_name`, doing a web search on it. Chances are it's available on some store, which then would give you the developer's name.

A different way is, as indicated by [ottucsak's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/105501/16575), extracting it from the certificate. The way to do that [is described here](http://www.herongyang.com/Android/Project-META-INF-Files-Digest-Signature-and-Certificate.html), and basically involves the following steps:

1. unpack the `.apk` file. As that's a `.zip` in its structure, unpacking would mean unzipping.
2. use `keytool` to view the certificate:
   `keytool -printcert -file META-INF\CERT.RSA`
3. in the output, check for the "Owner" and "Issuer" lines.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't really is possible. However there is a workaround. If you have got the `package name` of the `apk` you can see the developer name. Something like this: `com.<developer_name>.<app_name>`. Example: `com.google.drive`. If you don't know the package name you need to extract the `apk` and then the `package name` is somewhere in the `android-manifest` file.

Comment: Thanks, I have the package name and the apk too. It is a reverse engineering challange and I have decompiled into jar, but the developer's name isn't in the source files so I figured that I will have to look elsewhere to find the answer.

Comment: Just checked it, unfortunately this isn't correct. Is there any other field in which the developer's name/username/signature can be found?

Comment: No sorry, no other way

Comment: You could try google searching for the app/package name. Maybe then you can find the developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java Keytool to pull information about the developer.

```
keytool -printcert -file <extractedFile.RSA>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the developers name in the app's signature in the `*.apk/META-INF/CERT.RSA`